# Arduino compiler doesn't find a header file

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

In Arduino IDE 1.8.7 I pasted an old project into the directory "sketch_system1", my .ino file is sketch_system1.ino, all the headers, and C++ file are into the same directory as .ino file. When I try to compile I get this error:

```
Arduino:1.8.7 (Linux), Scheda:"Arduino/Genuino Uno"

sketch_system1:1:23: error: LumSensor.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
LumSensor.h: No such file or directory

Questo report potrebbe essere più ricco di informazioni abilitando l'opzione
"Mostra un output dettagliato durante la compilazione"
in "File -> Impostazioni"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with putting the .h and .cpp files into a directory with the same name of the .h and .cpp file, under the default directory library of arduino

Answer (score 0):

In my case a Microsoft Restore to a previous Restore Point on Windows 7 deleted all the library.properties files from the installed libraries.
Without those files later versions of Arduino expect the .h .cpp files to be in the top level of the libraries directory.
Add the library.properties files back from your backup (you have a backup don't you)
OR use the library manager to uninstall then reinstall the libraries to fix this.